A nonexistent object was used in an `Input` of a Dash callback
I am creating a multi tab dash app where one tab is to do with the technical aspects and the other the techno-economics, The issues I’m running into is that I keep getting A nonexistent object was used in an Input of a Dash callback. The id of this object is grid-input and the property is n_submit. This input exists in tab2 but not in tab1. I also have a side bar with dropdowns as well as an submit button. The issue I am getting is when I trigger the sidebar submit or the grid-value input in tab2 everything works however, when I trigger the sidebar in tab1 I get the error. Just to clarify tab2 contains 4 inputs "grid-input", "solar-input", "wind-input", "electrolyser-size" as well as the sidebar submit-button however the sidebar is not tab dependant and sits outside of the main dash
this is my current code:
app.layout = html.Div(
    id="big-app-container",
    children=[
        build_banner(),
        html.Div(combined_offcanvas),
        html.Div(
            id="app-container",
            children=[
                build_tabs(),
                dcc.Loading(
                    id="loading-central",
                    type="cube",
                    fullscreen=False,
                    style={"position": "absolute", "top": "50%", "left": "50%", "transform": "translate(-50%, -50%)"},
                    children=[
                        html.Div(id="app-content"),
                    ],
                ),
            ],
        ),
        dcc.Store(id="value-setter-store", data=create_pie_chart(capex_data, opex_data)),  # Update as needed
        generate_modal(),
    ],
)
# Callback to adjust percentage values
@app.callback(
    [Output('inflation-rate', 'value'),
     Output('discount-rate', 'value'),
     Output('tax-rate', 'value'),
     Output('grant-percentage', 'value'),
     Output('loan-percentage', 'value'),
     Output('loan-interest', 'value'),],
    [Input('inflation-rate', 'value'),
     Input('discount-rate', 'value'),
     Input('tax-rate', 'value'),
     Input('grant-percentage', 'value'),
     Input('loan-percentage', 'value'),
     Input('loan-interest', 'value'),],
    prevent_initial_call=True
)
def adjust_percentage_values(inflation_rate, discount_rate, tax_rate, grant_percentage, loan_percentage, loan_interest):
    def divide_by_100(value):
        if value is not None and value > 1:  # Adjust only if value seems unprocessed
            return value / 100
        return value
    
    return (
        divide_by_100(inflation_rate),
        divide_by_100(discount_rate),
        divide_by_100(tax_rate),
        divide_by_100(grant_percentage),
        divide_by_100(loan_percentage),
        divide_by_100(loan_interest),
    )
# Render Content Based on Tab Switch
@app.callback(
    Output("app-content", "children"),
    Input("app-tabs", "value"),
)
def render_tab_content(tab_switch):
    if tab_switch == "tab1":
        return html.Div(
            id="tab-1-status-container",
            children=[
                generate_metrics(total_CAPEX, lifetime_OPEX, total_lifetime_cost, cost_per_kg, cost_per_MWh, IRR, payback_time, NPV),
                html.Div(
                    id="cash-graphs-container",
                    children=[
                        dcc.Graph(
                            id='pie-chart',
                            figure=create_pie_chart(capex_data, opex_data)
                        ),
                        create_cumulative_cash_flow_chart(cf_summary)
                    ],
                ),
            ],
        )
    elif tab_switch == "tab2":
        return html.Div(
            id="status-container",
            children=[
                build_quick_stats_panel(electrolyser_size, grid_value, solar_value, wind_value),
                html.Div(
                    id="graphs-container",
                    children=[build_top_panel(), build_chart_panel()
                    ],
                ),
            ],
        )

@app.callback(
    Output("tab-1-status-container", "children"),
    [Input('submit-button', 'n_clicks')],
    [
        State('nuclear-electricity-cost', 'value'),
        State('water-cost', 'value'),
        State('hydrogen-sale-price', 'value'),
        State('depreciation-term', 'value'),
        State('inflation-rate', 'value'),
        State('project-lifespan', 'value'),
        State('discount-rate', 'value'),
        State('tax-rate', 'value'),
        State('grant-percentage', 'value'),
        State('loan-percentage', 'value'),
        State('loan-period', 'value'),
        State('loan-interest', 'value'),
        State('storage-amount', 'value'),
        State('dropdown1', 'value'),
        State('dropdown2', 'value'),
        State('dropdown3', 'value'),
        State('dropdown4', 'value'),
        State('dropdown5', 'value'),
        State('dropdown6', 'value'),
        State('dropdown7', 'value'),
        State('app-tabs', 'value'),
    ],
    prevent_initial_call=True
)
def update_excel_and_refresh_page_tab1(
    n_clicks, nuclear_cost, water_cost, hydrogen_sale_price, deprecation, inflation_rate, project_lifespan, discount_rate,
                   tax_rate, grant_percentage, load_percentage, loan_period, pre_tax_loan_interest, storage_amount , dropdown1, dropdown2, dropdown3, dropdown4,
                   dropdown5, dropdown6, dropdown7, tab_value):
    triggered_id = ctx.triggered_id

    if not ctx.triggered:
        raise dash.exceptions.PreventUpdate
    
    if tab_value == 'tab1':  # Check if the correct tab is active
        if triggered_id == "submit-button" and n_clicks:
            update_excel_cells(file_path, dropdown1, dropdown2, dropdown3, dropdown4,
                   dropdown5, dropdown6, dropdown7, nuclear_cost, water_cost, hydrogen_sale_price, deprecation, inflation_rate, project_lifespan, discount_rate,
                   tax_rate, grant_percentage, load_percentage, loan_period, pre_tax_loan_interest, storage_amount)
                        
            return html.Div(
                id="tab-1-status-container",
                children=[
                    generate_metrics(total_CAPEX, lifetime_OPEX, total_lifetime_cost, cost_per_kg, cost_per_MWh, IRR, payback_time, NPV),
                    html.Div(
                        id="cash-graphs-container",
                        children=[
                            dcc.Graph(
                                id='pie-chart',
                                figure=create_pie_chart(capex_data, opex_data)
                            ),
                            create_cumulative_cash_flow_chart(cf_summary)
                        ],
                    ),
                ],
            )



@app.callback(
    [Output("water-energy-consumption-graph", "figure"),
    Output("piechart", "figure"),
    Output("power-availability-graph", "figure"),
    Output("combined-sidebar-output", "children")],
    [
        Input('grid-input', 'n_submit'),
        Input('solar-input', 'n_submit'),
        Input('wind-input', 'n_submit'),
        Input('electrolyser-size', 'n_submit'),
        Input('submit-button', 'n_clicks')
    ],
    [
        State('grid-input', 'value'),
        State('solar-input', 'value'),
        State('wind-input', 'value'),
        State('electrolyser-size', 'value'),
        State('nuclear-electricity-cost', 'value'),
        State('water-cost', 'value'),
        State('hydrogen-sale-price', 'value'),
        State('depreciation-term', 'value'),
        State('inflation-rate', 'value'),
        State('project-lifespan', 'value'),
        State('discount-rate', 'value'),
        State('tax-rate', 'value'),
        State('grant-percentage', 'value'),
        State('loan-percentage', 'value'),
        State('loan-period', 'value'),
        State('loan-interest', 'value'),
        State('storage-amount', 'value'),
        State('dropdown1', 'value'),
        State('dropdown2', 'value'),
        State('dropdown3', 'value'),
        State('dropdown4', 'value'),
        State('dropdown5', 'value'),
        State('dropdown6', 'value'),
        State('dropdown7', 'value'),
        State('app-tabs', 'value')
    ],
    prevent_initial_call=True
)
def update_tab2_content(n_submit1, n_submit2, n_submit3, n_submit4, n_clicks, 
                        grid_value, solar_value, wind_value, electrolyser_size, nuclear_cost, water_cost, hydrogen_sale_price, deprecation, inflation_rate, project_lifespan, discount_rate,
                   tax_rate, grant_percentage, load_percentage, loan_period, pre_tax_loan_interest, storage_amount , dropdown1, dropdown2, dropdown3, dropdown4,
                   dropdown5, dropdown6, dropdown7, tab_value):

    triggered_id = ctx.triggered_id

    if not ctx.triggered:
        raise dash.exceptions.PreventUpdate

    if tab_value == 'tab2':
        if triggered_id in ["grid-input", "solar-input", "wind-input", "electrolyser-size", "submit-button"]:
            if triggered_id == "grid-input" and n_submit1:
                update_grid_solar_wind(file_path, electrolyser_size, grid_value, solar_value, wind_value)
            elif triggered_id == "solar-input" and n_submit2:
                update_grid_solar_wind(file_path, electrolyser_size, grid_value, solar_value, wind_value)        
            elif triggered_id == "wind-input" and n_submit3:
                update_grid_solar_wind(file_path, electrolyser_size, grid_value, solar_value, wind_value)        
            elif triggered_id == "electrolyser-size" and n_submit4:
                update_grid_solar_wind(file_path, electrolyser_size, grid_value, solar_value, wind_value)       
            elif triggered_id == "submit-button" and n_clicks:
                update_excel_cells(file_path, dropdown1, dropdown2, dropdown3, dropdown4,
                    dropdown5, dropdown6, dropdown7, nuclear_cost, water_cost, hydrogen_sale_price, deprecation, inflation_rate, project_lifespan, discount_rate,
                    tax_rate, grant_percentage, load_percentage, loan_period, pre_tax_loan_interest, storage_amount)
            else:
                raise dash.exceptions.PreventUpdate

    gd_boiled, gd_summary, gd_boiled_down, cf_summary, cs_capex_summary, cs_opex_summary = read_excel_data(file_path)

    # Example calculation based on updated data
    total_stack_water = gd_boiled['Stack Water Consumption'].iloc[0]
    total_purification_water = gd_boiled['Purification Water Consumption'].iloc[0]
    total_cooling_water = gd_boiled['Cooling Water Consumption'].iloc[0]

    # Update water consumption data for pie chart
    water_consumption_data = {...

    # Update power availability graph
    power_availability_figure = go.Figure(...

    hover_text = [f"{value} litres" for value in water_consumption_data['Total Consumption']]

    pie_figure = go.Figure(..

    water_energy_consumption_figure = go.Figure(...

    selected_values = (nuclear_cost, water_cost, hydrogen_sale_price, deprecation, inflation_rate, project_lifespan, discount_rate,
                   tax_rate, grant_percentage, load_percentage, loan_period, pre_tax_loan_interest, storage_amount, dropdown1, dropdown2, dropdown3, dropdown4,
                   dropdown5, dropdown6, dropdown7)

    return water_energy_consumption_figure, pie_figure, power_availability_figure, selected_values

